# What's the value from when on a number turned into string is printed in scientific notation?

Tags: php

I have large numbers in PHP and when I convert them to a string with `"" . $number`, they're printed in scientific notation with [X]E+[Y]. From what value on will PHP show this behavior? How do I force a big number to be converted to string digit by digit?

Comment: Please note that there is a reason for this presentation: check [PHP Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). *"If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead."*. And then floats have limited precision, so even if you wished to see all digits, they would not be correct.

Comment: just a note: why use `"". $number` to convert to string when you could use `(string) $number` ?

Comment: the number is PHP_INT_MAX (var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);)